# Tell background state of action extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, ios-extensions

`UIApplication` has the handy `applicationState` property that allows you to see if your application is in the background or not. In action (and share) extensions, use of `UIApplication` is illegal, and even if you *do* get an instance of it within an extension it always reports `applicationState=UIApplicationStateBackground`. I also tried observing `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`, it never fires.

Is there a way to effectively tell if an extension is running within an app that's in the foreground or background?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Post iOS 8.2, You can observe the notifications listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSExtensionContext_Class/).

`NSExtensionHostDidBecomeActiveNotification`
`NSExtensionHostWillResignActiveNotification`
`NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackgroundNotification`
`NSExtensionHostWillEnterForegroundNotification`

Be sure to check that you are on a device of the appropriate version before signing up for these notifications, or your extension will crash, as they will be `nil`.

Comment: Swift 3 format: NSNotification.Name.NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackground

Comment: I'm seeing that the didBecomeActive and willEnterForeground notifications don't fire the first time my sharing extension is used with the host app. They only occur the second, etc. time it is used.